# Is this case of ellipsis acceptable - "encourage in-migration to and inhibit out-migration from that province"?

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language, ellipsis

Is the following sentence acceptable in formal, academic writing?

> ... relatively higher UI benefits in a particular province encourage in-migration **to** and inhibit out-migration **from** *that province*.

While the sentence seems idiomatic to me, I am not sure if such a case of ellipsis is considered acceptable in a formal setting.

This sentence is different from other simple examples of ellipsis. For example, the omission of *regions* in  *"... reduced geographic mobility from low productivity to high productivity regions"* is completely fine in formal writing.

In my original sentence, I omitted the first *"that province"*, which left a hanging "to" there. I think the problem arises because the elements in the two predicates are different - *encourage in-migration* and *inhibit out-migration*.

I have seen constructions that use a parenthesis in such cases:

> ... relatively higher UI benefits in a particular province encourage in-migration **to** (and inhibit out-migration **from**) *that province*.

I don't know if that solves the problem or not. It does make it look better than " ... **to** and inhibit ...".

I am not asking for help in rephrasing the sentence. I can do that. I am interested in knowing if it is grammatical (if not, why?), and if it is acceptable in academic writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use "in-migration" and "out-migration" in place of the common words, "immigration" and "emigration"?

Apart from that, you could avoid the prepositions entirely:

"Relatively higher UI benefits in a particular province encourage immigration and inhibit emigration."

I think the reference to that particular province is clear.

Comment: Hello, *Immigration* and *emigration* are the wrong words for my purpose. Cambridge says "emigration" is *"the process of leaving a **country** permanently and going to live in another one"*. Collins says *"If you emigrate, you leave your **own country** to live in another country."* These words don't fit my meaning. Workers can relocate between different provinces, between different regions within a particular province, or between different center metropolitan areas. And such relocation can be temporary. In this case, the technical term that is used is "in-" and "out-migration". (cont.)

Comment: Of the 23 papers I reviewed on this subject, all have used "in-" and "out-". And I appreciate your answer, thanks. However, I don't particularly want to avoid the prepositions. I want to know if this case of ellipsis is grammatical, and if it is, then is the sentence appropriate for academic writing.

Comment: I understand now.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with that jargon. I think your original sentence is completely understandable and, as you said, idiomatic. Beyond that, I don't know.

Comment: @AIQ, maybe you could get a more authoritative answer on "English Language and Usage" than on ELL.

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for letting me know that the sentence is understandable. I have used the parenthesis just to make sure that the reader knows there is something to look out for. I guess without the parenthesis, one might be annoyed looking at *"... in-migration **to and** inhibit ..."* May be I am fretting over this too much.

Comment: I think you found a good solution.